# Run long running executable with output in gulp

Tags: gulp

I have a gulp-run task to run an .exe with arguments

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var run = require('gulp-run');

gulp.task("browserstack", function (done) {
    run("BrowserStackLocal.exe fooo localhost,4200,0").exec().pipe(gulp.dest('output'));
});
```

This works fine, and I get output:

> gulp browserstack
>   [10:08:36] Using gulpfile C:\bar\gulpfile.js
>   [10:08:36] Starting 'browserstack'...

But the .exe is long running and has it's own output to stdout in the meantime. When I run it from the command line (without gulp) it says something like *"running, press cntrl-c to stop"*. What I'm doing is waiting for it to finish and then writing it to file, which isn't quite right.

**How do I make it pipe the output to my gulp command line as it runs?**

Was a duplicate, here is my (windows-only) solution though:

```
gulp.task("browserstacklocal", function () {

    var bslocal = spawn('BrowserStackLocal.exe', ['foo', 'localhost,4200,0']);
    bslocal.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString());
    });
    bslocal.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data.toString());
    });
    bslocal.on('exit', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code.toString());
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, I assume stopping the gulp task will kill the running exe?

Comment: @SvenSchoenung Yep, perfect thanks.